# Conditionalizing bind mounted volumes for Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

**Please note:** my question mentions MySQL, but it is a Docker/Docker Compose volume management question at heart, and as such, should be answerable by anyone with decent experience in that area, regardless of their familiarity with MySQL.

---

My *understanding* is that Dockerized MySQL containers, when defined from inside a Docker Compose file like below, will be *ephemeral*, meaning they store all data on the container itself (no bind mounts, etc.) and so when the container dies, the data is gone as well:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-service-db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: $MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - $MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT:$MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_service_db_$MY_ENV
      MYSQL_USER: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD
  other-service-definitions-omitted-for-brevity:
    - etc.
```

To begin with, if that understanding is *incorrect*, please begin by correcting me! Assuming its more or less correct...

Lets call this **Ephemeral Mode**.

But by providing a bind mount volume to that service definition, we can specify an external location for where data should be stored, and so the data will persist across service runs (compose ups/downs):

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  my-service-db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: $MY_SERVICE_DB_HOST
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - $MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT:$MY_SERVICE_DB_PORT
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_service_db_$MY_ENV
      MYSQL_USER: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MY_SERVICE_DB_APP_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./my-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  other-service-definitions-omitted-for-brevity:
    - etc.
```

Lets call this **Persistent Mode**.

There are times when I will want to run my Docker Compose file in *Ephemeral Mode*, and other times, run it in *Persistent Mode*.

Is it possible to make the `volumes` definition (inside the Docker Compose file) conditonal somehow? So that sometimes I can run `docker-compose up -d <SPECIFY_EPHEMERAL_MODE_SOMEHOW>`, and other times I can run `docker-compose up -d <SPECIFY_PERSISTENT_MODE_SOMEHOW>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) that work together, where you have some base file and then other files that extend the definitions in the base file.

Without extra setup, Compose looks for `docker-compose.override.yml` alongside the main `docker-compose.yml`.  Since the only difference between the "ephemeral" and "persistent" mode is the `volumes:` declaration, you can have an override file that only contains that:

```yaml
# docker-compose.override.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-service-db:  # matches main docker-compose.yml
    volumes:      # added to base definition
      - ./my-service-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

You could also use this technique to move the actual database credentials and port publishing out of the main file into deploy-specific configuration.  It's also somewhat common to use it for setups that need to run a known Docker image in production but build it in development, and for setups that overwrite the container's contents with a host directory.

If you want the file to be named something else, you can, but you need to consistently provide a `docker-compose -f` option or set the [`COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file) every time you run Compose.

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.persistence.yml up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.persistence.yml ps
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.persistence.yml logs app

# Slightly easier (Linux syntax):
export COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.persistence.yml
docker-compose up -d
```

---

Philosophically, your application's data needs to be persisted *somewhere*.  For application containers, a good practice is for them to be totally stateless (they do not mount `volumes:`) and push all of their data into a database.  That means the database needs to persist data, or else it will get lost when the database restarts.

IME it's a little bit unusual to actively want the database to lose data.  This would be more interesting if it were straightforward to create a database image with seeded data, but the standard images are built in a way that makes this difficult.  In a test environment, still, I could see wanting it.

It's actually possible, and reasonable, to build an application that runs in Docker but uses an external database.  Perhaps you're running in a cloud environment, and your cloud provider has a slightly pricey managed database service that provides automatic snapshots and failover, for example; you could configure your production application to use this managed database and keep no data in containers at all.